# Add new column as array in Spark 3.1.1 java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i want to add one new column as array in my existing dataset. This is my existing dataset.

```
+----------------------+-------------------+
|col 1                 |col2               |
+----------------------+-------------------+
|val1                  |a                  |
|val2                  |b                  |
|val3                  |c                  |
--------------------------------------------
```

i have this static data

```
public static final String Dates = "2021-07-06,2021-07-07,2021-07-08";
```

i want result as follows

```
+----------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+
|col 1                 |col2               | col3                                   |
+----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------
|val1                  |a                  | [2021-07-06, 2021-07-07, 2021-07-08]   |
|val2                  |b                  | [2021-07-06, 2021-07-07, 2021-07-08]   |
|val3                  |c                  | [2021-07-06, 2021-07-07, 2021-07-08]   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Dataset data = Readdata();

i tried the following,

The below method works, but we need some build-in-functions and should avoid java code

```
Column[] new_data =
            Arrays.asList(Dates.split(",")).stream().map(functions::lit).toArray(Column[]::new);
data.withColumn("col3",array(new_data));
```

Can anyone have any suggestions?

i could do by using the below cmd

```
data
.withColumn("col3",lit(dates)) # add your string 
.withColumn("col3",split(col("col3"),",")) # Split your string
```

Now i got the desired result.
After that i applied `explode()` it will distribute col3 value to each row.

```
.withColumn("col3",explode("col3"))
```

and i got like this

```
+----------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+
|col 1                 |col2               | col3                                   |
+----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------
|val1                  |a                  | 2021-07-06                             |
|val2                  |b                  | 2021-07-06                             |
|val3                  |c                  | 2021-07-06                             |
|val1                  |a                  | 2021-07-07                             |
|val2                  |b                  | 2021-07-07                             |
|val3                  |c                  | 2021-07-07                             |
|val2                  |b                  | 2021-07-08                             |
|val3                  |c                  | 2021-07-08                             |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From this result dataset i created new column col4 based on col3 & col1(if col3 date is greater than particular date & col1 value greater than some value than col4 val is true otherwise false).

code is like this

```
data.withColumn("col4",when("col3".gt(Passing_one_date).and("col1".gt(lit(123))),lit(true))).otherwise(lit(false)));
```

Below is the result,

```
+----------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+----------------
|col 1                 |col2               | col3                                   | Col4           |
+----------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
|val1                  |a                  | 2021-07-06                             | true           |
|val2                  |b                  | 2021-07-06                             | false          |
|val3                  |c                  | 2021-07-06                             | true           |
|val1                  |a                  | 2021-07-07                             | true           |
|val2                  |b                  | 2021-07-07                             | false          |
|val3                  |c                  | 2021-07-07                             | true           |
|val1                  |a                  | 2021-07-08                             | true           |
|val2                  |b                  | 2021-07-08                             | false          |
|val3                  |c                  | 2021-07-08                             | true           |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data.filter("col4"); -> Selecting true values only

+----------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+----------------
|col 1                 |col2               | col3                                   | Col4           |
+----------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
|val1                  |a                  | 2021-07-06                             | true           |       
|val3                  |c                  | 2021-07-06                             | true           |
|val1                  |a                  | 2021-07-07                             | true           |
|val3                  |c                  | 2021-07-07                             | true           |
|val1                  |a                  | 2021-07-08                             | true           |
|val3                  |c                  | 2021-07-08                             | true           |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

this is the result. after applying explode row size gets increased. Which costs more if we do any further transform on it in the cloud.

Is there any possibility to remove the added rows after my filteration is done. col3 is no longer needed once the requirement is done.
iam currently checking with groupby and aggregation methods. Any suggestion would be helpful ?

Answer (score 2):

```
data
.withColumn("col3",lit(dates)) // add your string 
.withColumn("col3",split(col("col3"),",")) // Split your string
```

---

answering your 2nd part :

```
data.drop("col3").distinct()
```

Comment: One more question on this. after getting this column i applied explode(col3) and performed required operation. But my result dataset has many rows as i applied explode. Is it possible to remove that exploded rows only and get back the original number of rows without affecting my in between operation. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: It is difficult to answer without seeing your code/logic . why would you need to explode if you want old number of rows ?

Comment: i updated my current status and explained clearly :) - Thanks

Comment: Added to the answer.

Comment: Hello Sanket..Do u have an idea about this issue? <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68910764/upload-multiple-rows-from-dataset-to-gcp-storage-as-json-in-apache-spark-java>